# Will Chanterelle mushrooms grow under shrubs in my yard?

Tags: shrubs, growth, mushrooms

I would like to grow some Chanterelle mushrooms (*Cantharellus cibarius*) under some shrubs in my yard.  Will they grow in the narrow space between the shrubs?

Answer (score 2):

The [Chanterelle mushroom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanterelle) is a [mycorrhizal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza) fungus, which means it has a [symbiotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiosis) relation with specific plants. This will make it impossible to grow without it's associated plant.

From Wikipedia:

> Cantharellus species are found throughout the world in association with mycorrhizal host plants, including Africa, Europe, Asia, North America, South America, and Australia.
>
> Chanterelles are associated with either conifers or hardwood trees, depending on species. They are often found with oaks in California and Texas. In Scotland, chanterelles grow in mixed forests of silver birch and Scots pine, especially when the forest has plenty of moist, mossy undergrowth. In Fife they are common under beech. They are usually (but not always) found in the same places as wild blueberries. In Spain they associate with sweet chestnut. A walk in the woods after rain should prove fruitful from late July through the Autumn.